# Change video image preview to link or button link

Tags: html

https://bsde1234.github.io/videoFullscreen/

If you click image video go to full screen. I need a link or button link to click it and play video full screen.

Github link : https://github.com/bsde1234/videoFullscreen

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score -1):

You can use anchor tag and embed it in and use the target attribute to value "_self"
Most probably you will get it .

Comment: Give full code please